# TypeScript check function parameter is one of valid Enums

Tags: typescript, enums

I have several enums like so:

```
enum AuthCommands {
  LOGIN_REQUEST = "LOGIN_REQUEST",
  SIGNUP_REQUEST = "SIGNUP_REQUEST"
}

enum CustomerCommands {
  CUSTOMER_CREATE_REQUEST = "CUSTOMER_CREATE_REQUEST",
  CUSTOMER_UPDATE_REQUEST = "CUSTOMER_UPDATE_REQUEST",
  CUSTOMER_DELETE_REQUEST = "CUSTOMER_DELETE_REQUEST"
}
```

I then have an object of these Enums:

```
const Types = {
  AuthCommands,
  CustomerCommands
};
```

I then have the following function:

```
async create(id: string, eventType: Types) {}
```

This part `eventType: Types` is me trying to check that the caller of this method is calling it with an `eventType` parameter that is a valid member of one of those Enums. How would I achieve this?

(With the above, I obviously get the error `[ts] 'Types' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.`)

Is the `const Types` the right way to group Enums?

Comment: I would use an "or" in the parameter.  Not sure if it's the right way, but it compiles for me (not actually tested). `async create(id: string, eventType: AuthCommands | CustomerCommands) {}`  Look at "Union Types" at this link https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare "Types" as follow:

```
export type Types = AuthCommands | CustomCommands;
```